# node_modules/google-gax/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/index.js:47:11) at Module._compile on aws lambda

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe

I am accessing Cloud Pub/Sub API via @google-cloud/pubsub . But Iam getting Import . I have tried so many approaches which from stack over flow but nothing worked.

The Above Same functionality is working fine with local nodemodules .Why my lambda is not able to get those node modules .

```
module initialization error: Error
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/google-gax/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/index.js:47:11)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/grpc.js:37:14)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
```

Comment: did you find an answer to this?